# Random quotes in matrix block type

Tags: matrix, loop, random

I have a Matrix block with 2 types: quotes and text. The first block contains a quote and a text. The second and following ones only contain quotes.

I want the type text to be limited to 1 and the type quotes limited to one at a time displayed randomly.
Can't figure out how?

```
{% for block in entry.intro %}

    {% if block.type == "quote" %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <blockquote>
                <p>{{ block.quote|raw }}</p>
                <footer>{{ block.caption }} </footer>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    {% elseif block.type =="text" %}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 mb-xs-30">{{ block.column1 }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 mb-xs-30">{{ block.column2 }}</div>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query for your two blocks individually.

```
{% set quoteBlock = entry.intro.type('quote').first() %}
{% set textBlock = entry.intro.type('text').order('RAND()').first() %}

<blockquote>
    <p>{{ quoteBlock.quote|raw }}</p>
    <footer>{{ quoteBlock.caption }} </footer>
</blockquote>

<div>{{ textBlock.column1 }}</div>
<div>{{ textBlock.column2 }}</div>
```